# Merge Entries but only after X amount of entries

Tags: entries, merge

I'm trying to get entries from two sections and merge them together which is pretty straight forward using the merge filter.

For example, my sections are:

- News
- Promoted News

But, my main issue is I only want Entry 1 from **Promoted News** to appear after 2 entries in **News** and so on (In a 2 entry increment)

I don't want it like this:

- **News** - Entry 1
- **Promoted News** - Entry 1
- **News** - Entry 2
- **Promoted News** - Entry 2
- **News** - Entry 3
- **Promoted News** - Entry 3
- **News** - Entry 4
- **Promoted News** - Entry 4
- **News** - Entry 5
- **Promoted News** - Entry 5

But like this:

- **News** - Entry 1
- **News** - Entry 2
- **Promoted News** - Entry 1
- **News** - Entry 3
- **News** - Entry 4
- **Promoted News** - Entry 2
- **News** - Entry 5
- **News** - Entry 6
- **Promoted News** - Entry 3

I thought about doing it using a conditional and incrementing a variable, but I don't think this would work with pagination so I need to merge them in to one array.

Is it possible to do this? My heads mashed thinking about doing this...

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jason, did you ever get an answer to this? I am trying do something similar but with two different entry types, Thanks.

Comment: Sadly not :( I did consider writing a plugin to do this, but we never got round to it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a rather specific edge case, so I'd be surprised if there's something built in (nothing comes to mind). However, you could write a custom twig filter fairly easily to do this.