# Create a specific order of paginated entries by entry type

Tags: entries, entry-type, pagination

I am working with a design that requires entries to be laid out on a listing page in a specific order based on whether they are "Standard" or "Premium". The order of the paginated listing page is as follows:

- Standard, Standard,  Premium
- Standard, Standard, Standard, Standard
- Premium, Standard, Standard
- Standard, Standard, Standard, Standard
- Pagination

There could be a number of approaches with how I store the entries but my approach has been to set up a channel section "Offers" with two entry types "Standard" and "Premium". If the layout was not important I have the following working:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('offers').limit(14) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}

{% for entry in pageEntries %}
  {% if entry.type == 'premium' %}
    {% include "_includes/offers/listing-card-premium" %}
  {% endif %}
  {% if entry.type == 'standard' %}
    {% include "_includes/offers/listing-card" %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{# PAGINATIOIN NAV HERE #}
```

My question is, how do I achieve the above but using the specific order I need, whilst still paginating the entries and keeping track of what's been displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, you want to exclude the premium entries from the others? Carefull, code is not tested ;)

```
{% set premiumEntries = craft.entries({
    section: 'offers',
    entry-type: 'premium',
    order: 'postDate desc'
}) %}

{% set standardEntries = craft.entries({
    section: 'offers',
    entry-type: 'standard',
    order: 'postDate desc'
}) %}
```

Then you need to do a loop to merge the standard to the premium. 
Something like this
[Merge two arrays of ElementModels?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4475/merge-two-arrays-of-elementmodels)

... and finally paginate trough all of them. 
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Jan, any ideas, once I have merged the arrays in how to get that specific order. There is an almost identical question here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/21732/create-a-specific-order-of-paginated-entries-by-entry-type/21734#21734 but no real answer.

Comment: wrong link maybe? ;)

Comment: Oops infinite question loop error ;-) https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14002/merge-entries-but-only-after-x-amount-of-entries#comment29993_14002

Comment: ok, now I get exactly what you are trying to do. As I explained in my answer before I what seperate the entries first and them merge them together in a third object. So as I your order is not exactly systematic I would make a loop based on the premiumEntries object and with a simple if = 3 or 7 or 10 (if I counted right) I would merge an additional premiumEntries Entry to the new (third) object.